# Trying to merge data table rows/find sum of table rows in R by alphabetical order?

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe

Here is part of the data table I created:

[image]

[image]

I am trying to condense the gene rows into a single row with the 1s, 0s and -1s added together.

It would go from look something like this:

```
ABTB2  1 
ABTB2  0
ABTB2 -1
AIRE   0 
AIRE   1
AIRE   1
```

to looking like this:

```
ABTB2  0
AIRE   2
```

Comment: Using `dplyr`, this should work, assuming that your data table is called `df`: `df.sum <- summarise(group_by(df, geneAlph), d.sum = sum(d))`.

Comment: try `aggregate(d ~ geneAlph, FUN=sum, data=yourData)`

Comment: or `with(data, tapply(d, geneAlph, sum)`

Answer (score 1):

Data table is usually fastest, which is a great boon when you have millions of rows:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(mydata)[, n:=sum(d), by=geneAlph]

geneAlph n
1:    ABTB2  0
2:     AIRE  2
```